# Finding the slope of the steepest, shallowest line formed by two members of a set

Tags: geometry, optimization, set-theory, euclidean-geometry

Consider a non-empty set of cartesian coordinates in $2D$ space. We may assume that the set includes *at least* two *unique* members. It is possible that the set contains duplicated members. It may or may not be that all members are colinear.

I want to determine the slope of both the **steepest possible line** and the **shallowest possible line** that can be formed by two (or more) members of the set. Moreover, I want to do so as *efficiently* as possible.

The obvious, and perhaps the simplest answer, is to simply iterate over each member of the set, compute the slope of a line formed by that member and every other member, and keep track of that slope which is steepest/shallowest. As pointed out below, this probably has something like $O(\frac{1}{2}n^2)$ complexity. For a large number of points, however, this could be impractical.

Is there a better way?

Comment: I would think the complexity should be at most $n^2/2$, since for each point, there are $n-1$ points to test and the ordering of each pair of points doesn't matter.

Comment: @DOUGLASBRUNSON You have a point-- I think you're right. I'll correct the note above.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not well-versed in algorithms, but perhaps you can approach the problem geometrically.

1. For the steepest line, start by sorting the points by their $x$-coordinate, from smallest to largest.  Then, for each $x$-coordinate, draw a vertical line and rotate it by small amounts until in intersects another point and compute the slope (start with clockwise rotations, and then check CCW rotations).  Store the slope and move to the next point.  Hopefully, you would only need to check a few neighboring points for each point as you move from left to right, so that it is close to order $n$.
2. The same idea, but sort according to $y$-coordinate and moving from bottom to top with a horizontal line and slowly rotating as needed.